# EmguCV Skin Detection

Tags: c#, emgucv

I'm doing a skin detection method in c# using EmguCV. For skin detection I'm referring this [article](http://ac.aua.am/skhachat/Public/Papers%20on%20Face%20Detection/RGB-H-CbCr%20Skin%20Colour%20Model%20for%20Human%20Face%20Detection.pdf). I'm new in EmguCV. I just want to know how to get or set every pixel value of image that is capturing via webcam. If skin pixel matched it become white else black. I just want RGB value of pixel without degrading the performance of application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get or set every pixel value of image you do it easily as following

```
 Image<Bgr, Byte> img = ....

 for (i = 0; i < img.Height; i++)
 {
     for (k = 0; k < img.Width; k++)
     {
         // Get 
         // Color ( R, G, B, alpha) 
         Color c = img[i, k];

         // Set 
         img[i,k] = new Bgr();
      }
 }
```

it will be write inplace

Comment: I tried this code. It works fine on images but for live video feeds it slows down. Is there any techniques for background removal in emgucv. I tried _foreground detector technique also. but it also slows the program.

Comment: you could try some kind of masking to reduce the full image processing

Comment: do not access the img.height and width every loop - that is part of the problem.  Also there is a faster way to access the data in the image using pointers.